# Как вывести список дочерних страниц с кастомными полями Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Всем привет. Такой вопрос по Wordpress: есть родительская страница, на которую нужно вывести дочерние, на шаблоне страницы есть кастомные поля, сделанные с помощью плагина Magic Fields. Вывести список дочерних страниц удалось, но нужно вместе с этим вывести некоторые кастомные поля из этих дочек. Как это можно реализовать?
Вывести дочерние страницы получилось таким образом:

```
<ul>
            <?php
            wp_list_pages( array(
                'depth'        => 1,
                'title_li'    => '',
                'child_of'    => $post->ID,
                ) );
            ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Вам надо реализовывать цикл WordPress через WP_Query, а в цикле для каждой страницы выводить нужные кастомные поля.

Comment: Спасибо, буду мыслить в этом направлении)

Comment: Еще бы какой примерчик, не получается самостоятельно написать цикл)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо реализовывать цикл WordPress через WP_Query, а в цикле для каждой страницы выводить нужные кастомные поля.

```
global $post;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // Здесь ваш код
        echo $post->post_title; // Например, вывод названия страницы
        // Вывод кастомных полей
    }
} else {
    echo 'Нет записей';
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! То что нужно, где ты был раньше? )))

Comment: Я здесь почти всегда, надо было раньше зайти ))

Comment: а для чего два раза выполняется `wp_reset_postdata();`?

Comment: Да лишнее, конечно. Сейчас уберу.

Comment: А как это вывести на самой странице?

Answer (score 0):

```
     <!-- Карточки Начало цикла-->
                    <?php $penis = get_the_ID(); ?>
                    <?php   
                $sort = $_COOKIE["catalog_sort"];
                $show_count = (int)$_COOKIE["catalog_show_count"];
                $sort = str_replace('\\', "", $sort);
                $sort = json_decode($sort, true);

                if(!$show_count)
                    $show_count = 24;

                $queryArr = array(
                    'post_type'         => 'page',
                    'post_parent'       => $penis,
                    'meta_query'        => array(
                        "template"  => array(
                            "key"   => "_wp_page_template",
                            "value" => "templates/catalogue_detail.php",
                            "type"  => 'NUMERIC'
                        ),
                    ),
                    'paged'             => $currPage,
                    'posts_per_page'    => $show_count,
                    'order'             => strtoupper($sort["type"]),
                );

                if($sort)
                {
                    switch ($sort["by"]) {

                        case 'alphabet':
                            $queryArr["orderby"] = "title";
                            break;
                        case 'price':
                            $queryArr["meta_key"] = "item_price";
                            $queryArr["orderby"] = "meta_value_num";
                            break;
                    }
                }

                $query = new WP_Query( $queryArr );
                while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>
                <?php $aidi = get_the_ID(); ?>

<section class="section timetable">
            <div class="section__top section__top_page contacts__top" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field( "картинкарррррррррр" );?>')">
       <div class="section__content"></div>
      <svg class="section__triangle" viewbox="0 0 1000 105" preserveaspectration="none">
        <polygon class="section__polygon" points="0,10 0,105 800,105 800,120"></polygon>
        <polygon class="section__polygon" points="1000,0 1000,105 500,105 500,85"></polygon>
      </svg>
    </div>              
                 <div class="section__bottom graphics__bottom graphics__bottom_padding">
      <div class="section__wrapper courses__bg">
        <div class="section__content section__content_min">
          <div class="courses__wrap">
            <h1 class="section__img-desc section__img-desc_black"><?php the_title()?></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section__content">
      <ul class="section__list courses__display">




 <li class="section__item courses__item courses__item_one">
            <div class="section__item-wrap graphics__item">
              <div class="section__img">
                <div class="section__img-pic" style="background-image: url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>')"></div>
                <div class="section__img-desc courses__img-desc"><?php the_title()?></div>
              </div>
              <div class="section__desc">
                <div class="courses__desc-wrap">
                  <div class="courses__text section__text"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                  <div class="courses__num-lesson courses__title-num_darken"><?php the_field( "urokiaaa" );?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="section__controls"><a class="courses__btn section__btn section__btn_darken" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">подробнее</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>     




      </ul>
    </div>        </div>

  </section> 

                <?php
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_query();
                ?>

            <!-- Конец цикла -->
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]